# Open eclipse view along with custom editor in PDE

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, text-editor, eclipse-pde

I have created a custom eclipse editor and want a view to be opened in the event the editor is active. If the view is already open then nothing should be done. I also want this functionality for the console in that the console should be open in the event my custom editor is active. Is this possible to do in Eclipse plugin development environment?

Answer (score 0):

You can open the view in the `init` method of your editor using something like:

```
IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
page.showView("org.eclipse.ui.console.ConsoleView");
```

This will open the view if it is not open or make it the active view if it is already open.